# Meteor Project initialization error

Tags: node.js, meteor

Hi there trying to create my first meteor project on my desktop. When I try initialize my project after creation by entering the directory and entering meteor get and error. I am working on windows 10. I tried uninstalling/installing & deleting the .meteor folder. I am on node 5.6.0 and meteors 1.4.1.1.

```
C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.4.1_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\meteor-promise\promise_server.js:165
throw error;
^

TypeError: httpProxy.createProxyServer is not a function
at Proxy.start (C:\tools\runners\run-proxy.js:40:28)
at Runner.start (C:\tools\runners\run-all.js:119:16)
at Object.exports.run (C:\tools\runners\run-all.js:322:10)
at Command.doRunCommand as func
at C:\tools\cli\main.js:1410:23
```

Comment: you can find the github issue here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8069

Answer (score 1):

the definitive solution is:

remove folder "http-proxy" under c:\users\username\node_modules

Answer (score 0):

Try to change directory to the root of your new project, then run meteor.

```
$ cd my/directory/root
$ meteor
```

Comment: Yes thats when I get the error . D:\Documents\Work\test

Answer (score 0):

Before starting meteor, make sure you install the dependencies by running `npm install` or `meteor npm install` then run meteor.

[Meteor Tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app)

Comment: This might help you: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/7717. If not, try going back to Meteor 1.3 until they fix it.

Comment: Tryed going back to 1.3. Do you think its my OP System. Maybe a reset? . I really need to get meteor going soon

Comment: Have you tried with the example todos package? You could also tried with a different version of node. I'm on 5.2 and it works well.

Comment: I just tried creating the simple-todos app and got a similar error. that was because the `simple-todos` folder already existed. Is it that you are trying to create the project in an already existing folder?

Comment: Hi there i managed to fix the problem by reinstalling my windows system it was my last resort but works fine now